# How to label encode for a column in spark scala?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, rdd

I have a very big dataframe like:

```
    A     B
   a_1   b_1
   a_2   b_2
   a_3   b_3
   a_1   b_4
   a_2   b_4
   a_2   b_2
```

I want to create columns corresponding to each unique value of B and set its value as 1 if it exist for each unique value of A. The expected result should look like this

```
    A     B     C_b_1     C_b_2     C_b_3     C_b_4
   a_1   b_1      1         0         0         1
   a_2   b_2      0         1         0         1
   a_3   b_3      0         0         1         0
   a_1   b_4      1         0         0         1
   a_2   b_4      0         1         0         1
   a_2   b_2      0         1         0         1
```

**Explanation:** For a_1 the distinct values of B are {b_1, b_4} and hence the columns corresponding to them are set to 1. For a_2 the distinct values of B are {b_2, b_4} and hence those columns are 1. Similarly for a_3.

***The data is pretty huge, expect 'A' to have about 37000 distinct values while 'B' has about 370. The number of records are over 17 million.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.stat.crosstab`, and join it back to the original dataframe using the `A` column:

```
df.join(df.stat.crosstab("A","B").withColumnRenamed("A_B", "A"), "A").show
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|b_1|b_2|b_3|b_4|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|a_3|b_3|  0|  0|  1|  0|
|a_2|b_2|  0|  2|  0|  1|
|a_2|b_4|  0|  2|  0|  1|
|a_2|b_2|  0|  2|  0|  1|
|a_1|b_4|  1|  0|  0|  1|
|a_1|b_1|  1|  0|  0|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```